# Split an array when meets a certain number?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello I need to return count of chunks in given array of numbers.

Chunk can be defined assequence of one or more numbers separated by one or more zeroes.

```
Example: array [5, 4, 0, 0, -1, 0, 2, 0, 0] contains 3 chunks
```

so the answer should be 3 since the array can be split into three chunks.

Can you help me with the solution to this one?

Ive looped through the array but dont know how to deal with the multiple zeros.

Comment: What do you mean by if it meets number 0? Please add the expected output as well.

Comment: Your problem/explanation isn't very clear. You should also post your attempt so we can help better.

Comment: Why 3? If there are if the delimiter occurs 3 times in the array, shouldn't there be 4 chunks?

Comment: So the resulting chunks here would be `[5, 4]`, `[-1]` and `[2]` then? But you don't need those chunks, but only the count of them?

Comment: hello I edited my question what i need to do is count the chunks if its clearer :D

Comment: @CBroe yes  exactly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a flag for keeping track of counting the actual chunk and rest it only by fing a zero.

```js
let data = [5, 4, 0, 0, -1, 0, 2, 0, 0],
    count = 0,
    lastCount = false;

for (const value of data) {
    if (value === 0) {
        lastCount = false;
        continue;
    }
    if (!lastCount) {
        count++;
        lastCount = true;
    }
}

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you're interested in a good-performance, concise solution, in a single iteration...

Here's one based on [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops) library:

```
import {pipe, count, filter, split} from 'iter-ops';

const data = [5, 4, 0, 0, -1, 0, 2, 0, 0];

const c = pipe(
    data,
    split(v => v === 0), // split into chunks, by zero
    filter(a => !!a.length), // ignore empty chunks
    count() // count resulting chunks
).first; // take the first value (our count)

console.log(c); //=> 3
```

P.S. I'm the author of the library.

Answer (score 0):

If you needed to keep track of the chunks as well you can loop it using a simple for loop like so:

```js
var arr = [5, 4, 0, 0, -1, 0, 2, 0, 0];

var chunks = [];

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] !== 0){ // check that the current number isn't a 0
        if(arr[i - 1] === 0 || arr[i - 1] === undefined){ // check if previous number was a 0
            chunks.push([]); // add a new chunk if previous number was a 0
                }

        chunks[chunks.length - 1].push(arr[i]); // push the number to latest chunk
    }
}


//console.log(chunks);
console.log("There are " + chunks.length + " chunks");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by using Regular expressions.

```js
let array = [5, 4, 0, 0, -1, 0, 2, 0, 0];

let arrayToString = array.join("").toString();
let occurrenceRegex = /0+/g;  // Regex that will check for one or more occurrences

let result = arrayToString.match(occurrenceRegex).length; 

console.log(result); // Output: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution leveraging the second parameter of [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) within a [`while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) loop.

```js
function count_chunks(arr, delimeter = 0) {
  let count = 0, lastIndex = 0, index = 0;

  while (index !== -1 && lastIndex < arr.length) {
    index = arr.indexOf(delimeter, lastIndex);

    if (index - lastIndex) {
      count++;
    }

    lastIndex = index + 1;
  }

  return count;
}

const data = [5, 4, 0, 0, -1, 0, 2, 0, 0];
console.log(count_chunks(data));

// leading zero
console.log(count_chunks([0, 5, 4, 0, 0, -1, 0, 2]));
// no head or tail delimeters
console.log(count_chunks([5, 4, 0, 0, -1, 0, 2]));

// different delimeter
console.log(count_chunks([5, 4, 'x', 'x', -1, 'x', 2, 'x', 'x'], 'x'));
```